# How to check if a program is running as the current user via bat or cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How would i go about finding if a version of Outlook is running as a specific user?

I need to check and then if it's not open it under that logged in account.

I've tried a few suggestions from around the site but none are care about the logged in user

Some examples of what i have tried

```
-------------------------------
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq outlook.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "outlook.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Programm is running
----------------------
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /FO CSV > search.log

FOR /F %%A IN (search.log) DO IF %%~zA EQU 0 GOTO end

start notepad.exe

:end

del search.log
-------------------------------------
```

I can't install anything on the server and so would need an existing windows solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add another clause to your tasklist query like so?

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq outlook.exe" /FI "USERNAME eq %username%"
```

EDIT

Full script that should work.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq outlook.exe" /FI "USERNAME eq %username%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "outlook.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" start outlook.exe
```